# Why is Math Kernel Library for FFT so slow compared to FFTPack?

Tags: c, fft, intel-mkl, fftpack

I have been trying FFTPack from [CControl](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/). I C library that have a lot of math stuffs.
At the [fft.c](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Documents/Examples/SignalProcessing/fft.txt) example, I have been checking the difference between Intels Math Kernel Library, and just normally plain vanilla C-code from FFTPack.

If I have this example and then I try to comment/uncomment the macro `MKL_FFT_USED` inside the header [`defines.h`](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Headers/defines.h).

```
#include "CControl/ccontrol.h"

#define n 11000

int main() {
    clock_t start, end;
    float cpu_time_used;
    start = clock();

    /* Create x */
    float xr[n] = { -0.6485,   0.2851,   1.3475, -0.6743, -0.1499, -1.5549,   1.4951,   0.4504, -0.4982,   0.3488, 0.1 };
    float xi[n];

    /* Do FFT */
    fft(xr, xi, n);

    /* Print */
    //print(xr, 1, n);
    //print(xi, 1, n);

    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((float)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\nTotal speed  was %f\n", cpu_time_used);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get different results

When the macro `MKL_FFT_USED` is comment, I get the speed:

```
Total speed  was 0.001000
```

When the macro `MKL_FFT_USED` is uncomment, then I get the speed:

```
Total speed  was 0.009000
```

That means MKL is 9 times slower than FFTPack when it comes to FFT.

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/SignalProcessing/fft.c) of `fft.c`, it seems that the FFTPack have more code than MKL, but still FFTPack performs much better. The result is exactly the same, even if I implemented it in Matlab.

```
#include "../../Headers/functions.h"

/* Import the library FFTPack */
#ifndef MKL_FFT_USED
#include "FFTpack/fftpack.h"
#endif

/* 
 * Fast Fourier Transform 
 * xr[n] - Real values
 * xi[n] - Imaginary values
 * n - Data length
 */
void fft(float xr[], float xi[], size_t n) {
#ifdef MKL_FFT_USED
    /* Load data */
    MKL_Complex8* data = (MKL_Complex8*)malloc(n * sizeof(MKL_Complex8));
    size_t i;
    memset(data, 0, n * sizeof(MKL_Complex8));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i].real = xr[i];
    }

    /* Prepare FFT */
    DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE descriptor;
    DftiCreateDescriptor(&descriptor, DFTI_SINGLE, DFTI_COMPLEX, 1, n);
    DftiSetValue(descriptor, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_INPLACE);
    DftiCommitDescriptor(descriptor);

    /* Compute FFT */
    DftiComputeForward(descriptor, data);

    /* Load */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        xr[i] = data[i].real;
        xi[i] = data[i].imag;
    }

    /* Free */
    DftiFreeDescriptor(&descriptor);
    free(data);
#else

    /* Init */
    fftpack_real* wsave = (float*)malloc((2 * n + 15) * sizeof(fftpack_real));
    rffti(n, wsave);

    /* Forward transform */
    rfftf(n, xr, wsave);

    /* Fixing imaginary numbers */
    size_t i;
    memset(xi, 0, n * sizeof(float));
    size_t index = 0;
    xi += 1;
    for (i = 2; i < n; i += 2) {
        xi[n - index - 2] = -xr[i];
        xi[index++] = xr[i];
        xr[i] = 0;
    }
    
    /* Pack */
    const size_t half = n/2 + 1;
    for (i = 2; i < half; i++) {
        index = i + 1 + (i - 2);
        xr[i] = xr[index];
    }

    /* Mirror */
    index = half - (n % 2 == 0); /* if n % 2 == 0 is true, then 1(even), else 0(odd) */
    for (i = half; i < n; i++) {
        index--;
        xr[i] = xr[index];
    }

    /* Free */
    free(wsave);
#endif
}
```

**Question:**

Why is FFT much faster from FFTPack, compared to MKL? Notice, I'm not talking about FFT2D. FFT2D is much faster from MKL, compared to FFTPack. But for FFT1D, it seems that FFTPack wins the battle.

But I want to know why FFTPack for 1D is much faster than FFT for 1D from MKL? Have I missed I confiugration when i enabled MKL in my Visual Studio Community 2022?

[image]

Comment: Your benchmark is not very reliable - use a much larger FFT if possible, and loop for a significant number of times to get a decent average time (often there is a one-off overhead the first time you call a function so your obsevations may well be skewed by this).

Comment: You are including set-up time inside the measurement. The MKL routines to set up an FFT do special preparatory work so that the actual FFT computation is fast. Rewrite your code so all the memory allocation, `memset`, and other preparation is outside the time measurement.

Comment: Hi, Could you please get back to us with the MKL version or system configuration details (hardware architecture, OS version etc..) to triage the issue further?

Comment: @Shanmukh-Intel Windows 11, HP Elite Book 850 G8 and the MKL is the latest version. See CControl library at GitHub.